# Unexpected token: 'Map' for method that returns a Map

Tags: apex, map, sobject, method

Trying to create a method to return a Map of SObjects using any field I want (not Id or I would use the Map constructor that takes a List).

```
private static Map<String, SObject> getSObjectMap(List<SObject> records, String fieldName) {
  String sObjectTypeString = String.valueOf(records[0].getSObjectType());
  Type t = Type.forName('Map<String,' + sObjectTypeString + '>');
  Map<String, SObject> mapRecords = (Map<String, SObject>) t.newInstance();
  for (SObject record: records) {
    String key = (String) record.get(fieldName);
    mapRecords.put(key, record);
  }
  return mapRecords;
}
```

REVISED (per Derek F) Map variable name from "map" to "mapRecords" to resolve "Unexpected token: Map" and "Expecting ';' but was ','" and "Unexpected token: map" for the second line.

Comment: I was typing up an answer for your edit (which I thought should be a separate question). If you feel like making another question for it, I pretty much have an answer waiting for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` is a keyword, and it cannot be used as an identifier (the name of a variable, method, etc...).

Chose a different name for your variable, update the lines of code which use that variable, and you should be fine.

### +edit:

To be a bit more specific, you can't use a reserved word (loop, and, map, etc...) as an identifier by itself, but it *can* be part of an identifier. `myMap`, `ripAndTear`, etc... There just needs to be something to prevent the compiler (parser?) from thinking it's something it isn't.

Comment: Thanks... Wish I got a message like "Reserved name: map". The error messages were taking me in the wrong direction.

Comment: @nstuyvesant Making a compiler that gives useful error messages is hard, so I don't really fault Salesforce too much for that. There is a [doccumentation page for reserved words](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm). Another thing to keep in mind is that Apex is pretty case-insensitive. `'Map' == 'map' == 'MAP'` (anything that involves hashes though, like data put into a `Set` or the key of a `Map` is very much case-sensitive).

Comment: Thanks @Derek F. Knowing Apex is not case-sensitive is helpful as I've seen references to SObject and sObject in Salesforce's code examples that had me scratching my head.

Comment: While this is syntactically correct, I guess my approach is problematic.